# Vue.use vs Vue.component on root Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

`Vue.use` makes functionality global whilst calling `Vue.component` in the root Vue component (typically `app.vue`) has the same effect. I've seen a sample app using both (many `Vue.component` and `Vue.use` calls within the root js). Have been googling but don't see anything explaining this pattern.

What is the (subtle) difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters see:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use

It's a bit vague to say *'making functionality global'*. There's a need to pin down a bit more clearly exactly what that means in each case.

`Vue.component` is used to register a **component** globally. That makes it available within templates by the specified name. So `Vue.component('rainbow', componentDefinition)` will allow you to use `<rainbow>` within all your templates without having to explicitly import it into those components. For more information about the different ways to register components see:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

`Vue.use` is used to invoke a plugin. Effectively a plugin is just a JavaScript function and it can do whatever it wants. That function might register components (using `Vue.component`) but many plugins do other things, such as registering directives or adding global mixins.

It may well be that in the sample app you're studying the plugins are all registering components, which gives the impression that `Vue.use` is much the same as `Vue.component`. If so, that's just a coincidence. I suggest that you take a look at the source code for some of the plugins to get a better idea of what they're doing and how they work.

Both `Vue.component` and `Vue.use` will typically be used in the main entry point file for your application. Likely that'll be called something like `main.js`. They might not be called directly, for example a plugin might call `Vue.component`, but the global nature of their outcomes usually makes it necessary to make all such calls prior to kicking off the application itself with `new Vue`.

If you've got `Vue.component` or `Vue.use` calls inside a `.vue` file then that suggests you're doing something wrong, even if it's `app.vue`. A `.vue` file should just export a component, it shouldn't have any global side-effects such as registering components.

Comment: True...all this was loaded in the main.js